# why use Uri with VideoViewer?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

Two different codes:

```
video.setVideoPath("https://www.dropbox.com/s/lo9pr0ov1i9u1if/colorcompose-1.webm?dl=1");
...
video.start();
```

---

```
String videopath = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/iazx7fekjd8o4tw/sn2008.mp4?dl=1"; 
Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
...
video.start();
```

Both work well.

Why use Uri declarations ? Any difference in performance ?

Comment: yes, java for android. Android Studio. it is code to play video on smartphone. It's my first post, did I publish in wrong place ?

Answer (score 0):

Becuase Uri CLass is the interest of performance, this class performs little to no validation. Behavior is undefined for invalid input. This class is very forgiving--in the face of invalid input, it will return garbage rather than throw an exception unless otherwise specified.